# SSRS Using existing datasets to work out population and accountability

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have 2 datasets within a report, 1 holds the total population and the 2nd holds reviews. What I need to do within a field is show the % done. e.g. dataset1.[Reviews] where Status =  "incomplete" and Status = "high risk" / dataset2.[Population] where type = "high risk"

Population Data example:

- NAME, RISK LEVEL
- Client123, HIGH RISK
- Client124, MEDIUM RISK
- Client125, HIGH RISK
- Client126, HIGH RISK
- Client127, HIGH RISK
- Client128, HIGH RISK

Review Data example

- CLIENT NAME, REVIEW STATUS
- Client123, INCOMPLETE
- Client124, COMPLETE
- Client125, COMPLETE
- Client126, INCOMPLETE
- Client127, INCOMPLETE
- Client128, INCOMPLETE

So 5 HIGH RISK Population, with 4 reviews incomplete = 80% delinquent

I need to try and do this in an expression and for the life of me I'm struggling! Maybe it's Friday brain!?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to use LOOKUP but it would be helpful if you could EDIT YOUR QUESTION and share some sample data from each dataset and the expected results based on your sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below **screenshots and steps** to get desired output 
 
[Sample Output[image: Sample Output]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZQ6v.jpg)

[Expression Details[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLuAR.jpg)

[Row Group Details - 1[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Lsk.jpg)

[Row Group Details - 2[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avd6P.jpg)

**DataSet1**

```
select 'Client123' as [NAME],'HIGH RISK' as [RISK LEVEL]
union all
select 'Client124' as [NAME],'MEDIUM RISK' as [RISK LEVEL]
union all
select 'Client125' as [NAME],'HIGH RISK' as [RISK LEVEL]
union all
select 'Client126' as [NAME],'HIGH RISK' as [RISK LEVEL]
union all
select 'Client127' as [NAME],'HIGH RISK' as [RISK LEVEL]
union all
select 'Client128' as [NAME],'HIGH RISK' as [RISK LEVEL]
```

**DataSet2**

```
select 'Client123' as [CLIENT NAME] , 'INCOMPLETE' as [REVIEW STATUS]
union all
select 'Client124' as [CLIENT NAME] , 'COMPLETE' as [REVIEW STATUS]
union all
select 'Client125' as [CLIENT NAME] , 'COMPLETE' as [REVIEW STATUS]
union all
select 'Client126' as [CLIENT NAME] , 'INCOMPLETE' as [REVIEW STATUS]
union all
select 'Client127' as [CLIENT NAME] , 'INCOMPLETE' as [REVIEW STATUS]
union all
select 'Client128' as [CLIENT NAME] , 'INCOMPLETE' as [REVIEW STATUS]
```

**Expression used in this report**

`1. Lookup(Fields!NAME.Value, Fields!CLIENT_NAME.Value, Fields!REVIEW_STATUS.Value, "DataSet2")`

`2. count(Lookup(Fields!NAME.Value, Fields!CLIENT_NAME.Value, Fields!REVIEW_STATUS.Value, "DataSet2"))`

`3. count(Lookup(Fields!NAME.Value, Fields!CLIENT_NAME.Value, Fields!REVIEW_STATUS.Value, "DataSet2"))/Count(Fields!NAME.Value,"RISK_LEVEL")`

`4. Count(Fields!NAME.Value, "RISK_LEVEL2")`

I have created two sample report. I mentioned group properties of `sample report1`. For `sample report2` the group property like as first one.

Comment: Thank you very much Soundappan